# Shutdown vs Hibernate boot speed

Tags: windows-10, boot, shutdown, hibernate, win10-fast-startup

I want to know is booting after hibernation faster or booting after shutting down in windows 10. (Fast startup enabled). I know that windows 10 fast startup is similar to hibernation but I want to know would hibernation be even faster? (Hibernating when no program is open)

Comment: You have always programs open, usually a lot of autostart apps (see tray or taskmanager) but at least one program is always open: the Windows Explorer showing the desktop and the task bar + start menu button.

Comment: Try it. Some computers cold-boot (without fast startup) very fast, so nothing can make a big difference. Other computers... Just try and see for yourself unless there is a problem trying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate is faster because an image is written to disk with all the running programs.

Startup (even Fast) has to load a number of things.

Still, test Hibernate well because it is a problem on some machines.

I can suspend and let the machine sit overnight, so I use Suspend in preference to Hibernate and Suspend recovery is even faster.

Comment: Do you mean sleeping by suspending?

Comment: Sleep and ordinary suspend are the same (I am not talking about Hybrid Sleep which progressively moves toward hibernate while it is sleeping). I mean just regular suspend.